# Are EventTargets required to provide corresponding handler properties?

Tags: javascript, html, standards

I assume it's well understood *in practice* that objects which implement `EventTarget` include all of their supported events as properties with `on` prefixes in their keys. For example, [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is paired with the [WindowEventHandlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers) mixin, allowing code like:

```
window.addEventListener('print', foo);

// ...or

window.onprint = foo;
```

But does a standard *mandate* that for every possible event name `X` there must be an associated `onX` property on that same `EventTarget`? Or is that just a convention browsers happened to follow as a historical artifact?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML living standard covers this.

[Excerpt](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes):

> Event handlers are exposed in two ways.
>
> The first way, common to all event handlers, is as an event handler IDL attribute.
>
> The second way is as an event handler content attribute. Event handlers on HTML elements and some of the event handlers on Window objects are exposed in this way.
>
> For both of these two ways, the event handler is exposed through a name, which is a string that always starts with "on" and is followed by the name of the event for which the handler is intended.

The IDL and content attributes do not determine the taxonomy of event names, but since [IDL attributes are visible as properties in JS without a `setAttribute` or `getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#Content_versus_IDL_attributes), then the above passage basically says that every event handler must get exposed as a property with an `on`-prefixed name.

That being said, the JS object that has these property names *might not be the actual target of the event*. The living standard cites `body` as one example of an element with IDL attributes for handlers targeting a corresponding `Window` instance... Even though the `body` element itself implements `EventTarget`.

So in general, it's your responsibility to verify the target, but you can at least count on every standard event `N` corresponding `onN` property that you can set on some `EventTarget` in your JavaScript source.